# m is not a function - Highcharts-more

Tags: highcharts

i'm working with a gauge of highcharts and i have this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: m is not a function
    at highcharts-more.js:22
    at highcharts-more.js:27
    at highcharts-more.js:8
    at highcharts-more.js:8
```

Think that is a js issue, because i'm using other graphs that work correctly. I have this issue since use the highcharts-more js file to resolve this error

https://www.highcharts.com/errors/17

That is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>RealTimeMio</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">
  <!-- CSS Files-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/core.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/inputs.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/anims.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/global.css">

  <!-- CSS Files usati in dashboard -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link href="assets/lib/amcharts/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- jQuery Files-->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/inputs.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/functions.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery Files dashboard -->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/sparkline.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/flot.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/justgage.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/tablesorter.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/standalone-framework.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/highstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.ba-resize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/themes/frontpage-theme.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">

    <app-root>
      <div id="load">
        <div id="spinner"></div>
        <div id="load-inner"></div>
      </div>
    </app-root>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And these is my options for the gauge

```
chart: {
            renderTo: 'graficoMisuratoreAnalogico',
            type: 'gauge',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            plotBackgroundColor: {
              linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
              stops: [
                [0, '#FFF4C6'],
                [0.2, '#FFFFFF'],
                [1, '#FFF4C6']
              ]
            },
            plotBackgroundImage: null,
            height: 225
          },

          title: {
            text: 'Misurazioni voltmetriche'
          },

          pane: [{
            startAngle: -45,
            endAngle: 45,
            background: null,
            center: ['16%', '80%'],
            size: 200
          }, {
            startAngle: -45,
            endAngle: 45,
            background: null,
            center: ['50%', '80%'],
            size: 200
          }, {
            startAngle: -45,
            endAngle: 45,
            background: null,
            center: ['84%', '80%'],
            size: 200
          }],

          yAxis: [{
            min: 190,
            max: 280,
            minorTickPosition: 'outside',
            tickPosition: 'outside',
            labels: {
              rotation: 'auto',
              distance: 20
            },
            plotBands: [{
              from: 190,
              to: 207,
              color: 'red',
              innerRadius: '100%',
              outerRadius: '105%'
            }, {
              from: 255,
              to: 280,
              color: 'red',
              innerRadius: '100%',
              outerRadius: '105%'
            }],
            pane: 0,
            title: {
              text: 'V<br/><span style="font-size:8px">Channel R</span>',
              y: -20
            }
          }, {
            min: 190,
            max: 280,
            minorTickPosition: 'outside',
            tickPosition: 'outside',
            labels: {
              rotation: 'auto',
              distance: 20
            },
            plotBands: [{
              from: 190,
              to: 207,
              color: 'red',
              innerRadius: '100%',
              outerRadius: '105%'
            }, {
              from: 255,
              to: 280,
              color: 'red',
              innerRadius: '100%',
              outerRadius: '105%'
            }],
            pane: 1,
            title: {
              text: 'V<br/><span style="font-size:8px">Channel S</span>',
              y: -20
            }
          }, {
            min: 190,
            max: 280,
            minorTickPosition: 'outside',
            tickPosition: 'outside',
            labels: {
              rotation: 'auto',
              distance: 20
            },
            plotBands: [{
              from: 190,
              to: 207,
              color: 'red',
              innerRadius: '100%',
              outerRadius: '105%'
            }, {
              from: 255,
              to: 280,
              color: 'red',
              innerRadius: '100%',
              outerRadius: '105%'
            }],
            pane: 2,
            title: {
              text: 'V<br/><span style="font-size:8px">Channel T</span>',
              y: -20
            }
          }],

          plotOptions: {
            gauge: {
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.2f} V',
                y: 30
              },
              dial: {
                radius: '100%'
              }
            }
          },


          series: [{
            data: [230],
            yAxis: 0
          }, {
            data: [230],
            yAxis: 1
          }, {
            data: [230],
            yAxis: 2
          }]
```

Comment: Can you please try replacing your `highcharts-more.js` script inclusion with `highcharts-more.src.js` from here => http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.src.js and ping me the descriptive error it is throwing?

Comment: Do you use the same version of your highstock.js and highcharts-more.js?